# echo-area: disable help messages

Tags: help, echo-area, inhibit-message

I get the following in my minibuffer and I want to disable these basic help messages. Anyone know how?

```
Type C-x 1 to delete the help window
Type "q" in help window to restore it's previous buffer
```

Looks like it comes from `help-window-display-message`.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer here:
https://superuser.com/questions/669701/emacs-disable-some-minibuffer-messages

You suppress the message with advice-add

```
(defun suppress-messages (old-fun &rest args)
  "Suppress messages from OLD-FUN with ARGS.
https://superuser.com/questions/669701/emacs-disable-some-minibuffer-messages"
  (cl-flet ((silence (&rest args1) (ignore)))
    (advice-add 'message :around #'silence)
    (unwind-protect
         (apply old-fun args)
      (advice-remove 'message #'silence))))

(advice-add 'help-window-display-message :around #'suppress-messages)
```

Comment: Or simply `(advice-add 'help-window-display-message :around #'ignore)`